# Unable to find nested elements after page loading

Tags: angular, protractor

In a test spec, I need to click a button on the Home page, and wait for the page completely loaded. The button was clicked only once and when I rerun the spec it fails due to protractor is not able to reach the end of the nested elements on `element(by.tagName('app-banner')`

```
it('should click a button',  async () => {
    const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    page.login().then(() => {
      browser.wait(element(by.id('Body')).element(by.tagName('app-root')).isDisplayed, 5000).
      then(async () => {
        browser.wait(await element(by.tagName('app-root')).element(by.tagName('app-banner')).isDisplayed, 5000).
        then(async () => {
         await element(by.tagName('app-root')).element(by.tagName('app-banner')).
          element(by.id('topbar')).element(by.id('user-display')).click();
          });
        });
      });
  });
```

-- HTML Hierarchy

```
<app-home>
   <div _ngcontent-c1 class=”layout-wrapper”>
     <app-banner>
       <div _ngcontent-c3 id=”topbar”>
          <a id=”user-display”>
             <bar-switchuser>
                <span>
                    <p-dropdown>
                    </p-dropdown>
                </span>
             </bar-switchuser>
           </a>
        </div>
    <app-banner>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the html as well please

Comment: I have added the HTML elements hierarchy. Thanks!

Comment: try to wait for the app banner like this:
                    var checkExist = setInterval(function() {            
                        if ( element(by.id('user-display')) ){
                           clearInterval(checkExist);
                        }
                     }, 1000); // check every 1000ms
                 
Also, did you check if the element want to click is not dynamic? sometimes the first id is always the same but if you refresh the page or change something a new id or something else will change

Comment: I have tried that solution but protractor doesn't wait for setInterval! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `ExpectedConditions` but don't use it. Why? Use it instead `isDisplayed`:

`await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element(by.id('Body')).element(by.tagName('app-root')), 5000, "Element is not visible in 5 sec")`

Comment: I have tried that, but I'm still having the same issue!